# Displaying a ListView on Android, using an adapter with info from a nested class

Tags: java, android, listview, gson

I'm tring to retrieve a json, store its data on a class, then show it on a ListView.

I am getting a nullpointerexception and I think it is because I'm making some mistake retrieving the infomation from the array of DaysList.

This is the main fragment, I'm not sure if the array declaration is fine. :

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private View view;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private WeatherAdapter weatherAdapter;
public WeatherForecast weatherForecast;
public WeatherForecast.DaysList[] daysForecast;

private ListView listview;

String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Rosario,ar&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=3&appid=c8ca9280dc6e2ebeb82e7fa63b2104fb";
String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment,null);

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista_forecast);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonWeatherRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    weatherForecast = parseWeatherToJson(response.toString());
                    daysForecast = weatherForecast.getDays();
                    weatherAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "On Error!");
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonWeatherRequest);

    weatherAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listview_item,daysForecast);    //  This is where i get the nullpointer .
    listview.setAdapter(weatherAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

This is my custom adapter:

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
WeatherForecast.DaysList[] daysList;

TextView dt;
TextView pressure;
TextView humidity;


public WeatherAdapter (Context context, int layoutResourceId, WeatherForecast.DaysList[] daysList) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, daysList);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.daysList = daysList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        dt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dt);
        pressure = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pressure);
        humidity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.humidity);
    }

    WeatherForecast.DaysList day = daysList[position];
    dt.setText(day.getDtString());
    pressure.setText(day.getPressureString());
    humidity.setText(day.getHumidityString());

    return row;
}
}
```

This is the WeatherForecast class. I only created a few getters to test the funcionality.:

```
public class WeatherForecast {

public City city;
public int cod;
public float message;
public int cnt;
public DaysList[] dayList;

public int getCnt() {return cnt;}
public String getCod() { return String.valueOf(cod);}
public DaysList[] getDays() { return dayList;}

public class City {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Coord coord;
    public String country;
    public int population;

    public String getName() {return name;}
}

public class Coord {
    public double lon;
    public double lat;
}

public class DaysList {
    public int dt;
    public Temp temp;
    public double pressure;
    public int humidity;
    public Weather[] weather;
    public double speed;
    public int deg;
    public int clouds;

    public String getDtString() {return String.valueOf(dt);}
    public String getPressureString() {return String.valueOf(pressure);}
    public String getHumidityString() {return String.valueOf(humidity);}
}

public class Temp {
    public double day;
    public double min;
    public double max;
    public double night;
    public double eve;
    public double morn;
}

public class Weather {
    public int id;
    public String main;
    public String description;
    public String icon;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong retrieving that array?

edit: the parsing method using Gson.

```
private WeatherForecast parseWeatherToJson(String jsonObject) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    WeatherForecast weather = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, WeatherForecast.class);
    return weather;
}
```

Comment: first set your adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Please paste your parseWeatherToJson() function in comment that will help to find your issue.

Comment: Sure, im using Gson to parse the Json. Added to the OP.

Comment: Just in case someone comes around this topic, i think something that's wrong with my implementation is that Gson store data structures in Lists instead of arrays. Im switching and will see if that works..